# What is the best way to translate the response message from the server?

Tags: android

Android application is interacting with the server and sometimes server send error messages. Message consists of a code and a String message itself. On client I have `strings.xml` with different translations. What is the best way to get the right translated string from `strings.xml` file?

I am choosing between:

- Put all messages into the HashMap and than get the String from the strings.xml file
- Do selection of ErrorCode inside of `switch()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would definitely favour the latter approach i.e returning error code from server which can then be mapped to local string.